How to label or add a metadata comment to branches in Github.com
In Github.com, we have ~300 branches on a repo - it's hard to keep the repo tidy. Some of them can be removed, but it's a large project, so we don't all know each other to know if it's safe to do so.
We need a way to label them (besides the branch name) with the bug number or the person/team who uses the branch so we can tell a date/who/what/when/where each branch is used for, and to clean up periodically.
I see that there is something called a branch description. However, this works locally in git bash, and not uploaded to Github.com as far as I can tell.
-- to set a branch description metadata 
git branch --edit-description
<set the description in the text editor>

-- to read all branch .descriptions
git config --get-regexp branch.*.description

I tried to set the description using --edit-description as shown above, and it saves it, but don't see it anywhere in github.com when I push. Maybe Github.com doesn't show/support branch descriptions.
Are there any other ways to tag/label metadata on branches so we can know when/who/why they were created?
